# Can't write files to uSD card: looks like they're created but when I remount the card they're gone

Tags: 19.10, exfat, fuse

I can't seem to create files on my uSD card. No error is given and it looks like the file is there until I unmount and remount the filesystem and then everything is gone.

Simplest steps to recreate:

- Insert uSD card in port
- cd to mount point (/media/$USER/6139-3562)
- touch test.txt
- ls (lists test.txt)
- cd ..
- umount 6139-3562 (unmounts successfully)
- reinsert card
- cd 6139-3562
- ls (no test.txt listed, other prexisting files are there)

fdisk output:

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 59.49 GiB, 63864569856 bytes, 124735488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device         Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1      32768 124735487 124702720 59.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, the uSD card in question was faulty and failed to write under Windows as well. Other exFAT SD Cards were able to be written under Ubuntu.